# Hazelcast: disable clustering

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast on a java project, but I only use a single node and do not want any clustering. It's actually causing us issues when several dev instances discover each other and form a cluster.

Is there a way to fully disable clustering in the xml configuration?

Edit: I'm using Hazelcast 3.8.4, I've tried disabling multicast like so, but it looks like it's still enabled:

```
    <hz:hazelcast id="hazelcast">
        <hz:config>
            <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
            <hz:properties>
                <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">slf4j</hz:property>
            </hz:properties>
            <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
                <hz:join>
                    <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                </hz:join>
            </hz:network>
            <hz:topic name="topicStuff"/>
        </hz:config>
    </hz:hazelcast>
```

Logs:

```
12:54:51,273 INFO  [com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory] - Starting up HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory
12:54:51,284 INFO  [com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator] - Loading 'hazelcast-default.xml' from classpath.
12:54:51,398 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] - [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.4] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
12:54:51,409 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker] - [LOCAL] [dev] [3.8.4] Picked [10.212.134.200]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true 
12:54:51,426 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Hazelcast 3.8.4 (20170809 - 297a77e) starting at [10.212.134.200]:5701
12:54:51,426 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
12:54:51,426 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
12:54:51,648 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Backpressure is disabled
12:54:52,088 INFO  [com.hazelcast.instance.Node] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Creating MulticastJoiner
12:54:52,219 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Starting 12 partition threads 
12:54:52,220 INFO  [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Starting 7 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
12:54:52,241 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] [10.212.134.200]:5701 is STARTING
12:54:54,286 INFO  [com.hazelcast.system] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] Cluster version set to 3.8
12:54:54,289 INFO  [com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] 


Members [1] {   Member [10.212.134.200]:5701 - 820072f4-f1ef-4a5e-9722-eb2bd038f37e this }

12:54:54,361 INFO  [com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService] - [10.212.134.200]:5701 [dev] [3.8.4] [10.212.134.200]:5701 is STARTEDsdf
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When no join method is enabled, Hazelcast starts in standalone mode. Prior to version 4.1, the default join method is multicast and when it's disabled, the member will start standalone:

```
<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"/>
    </join>
</network>
```

which yields the log:

```
WARNING: [192.168.1.3]:5701 [dev] [4.0] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
```

With version 4.1, this becomes

```
<network>
    <join>
        <auto-detection enabled="false"/>
    </join>
</network>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it may be something like that but couldn't find any info in the docs I've read so far.

Comment: The question is now: why does hazelcast ignores my enabled="false" and still create the MulticastJoiner and the cluster...

Comment: Can you provide the Hazelcast version you encountered this?

Comment: 3.8.4, I've edited the question with more details

Comment: In the logs I see hazelcast-default.xml is picked up by the member. Is that the xml file you actually make your configurations? Or else it's the one comes along the jars? May be you change the group name in the config to some other value and then check logs to see if it's the config which members actually use. I feel like you do not pass your config location to your app and hence Hazelcast uses the default - no matter which join method you set in your config.

Comment: I've seen that line too. My configuration file is named differently, and it's imported by my application.properties. I can see it being picked up by spring, and it's definitely read because if I make a mistake in it, I have an error: "12:54:49,168 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/path/to/webapp/target/classes/applicationContextHazelcast.xml]" I'll check that more.

Comment: The WTF deepens, I apparently have two hazelcast instances starting. One through spring, which does correctly use my config file and disable the cluster. And another one through hibernate, which is apparently hazelcast for its cache :<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastLocalCacheRegionFactory" />. And that one uses the default file from the jar. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw it's caused by Spring's auto-configuration utility. However you can disable this via `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HazelcastAutoConfiguration.class)` and prevent Spring to create Hazelcast instance when it notices a Hazelcast configuration within the application context.

Comment: I want spring to create it actually, so I have all my configs in the same place. It does actually work, I was just looking at the wrong logs, the one of the instance started by hibernate (which is using the default file), I'll probably remove that instance altogether.